# How to use connection pooling for Monetdb?

Tags: connection-pooling, monetdb

Can some tell me how to use connection pooling with MonetDb? Do I just append these args to the URL "poolminimum=1;poolmaximum=5;"?

Answer (score 0):

No, by itself, the driver does not pool connections. You could use c3p0 (http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) to create a connection pool for MonetDB JDBC connections. However, please be aware that MonetDB uses optimistic concurrency control and table-level locking, so firing updates at a single table from multiple connections will have an increasing risk of transaction aborts. For reading however, this should be fine.