# connection pooling with MonetDB, R and Shiny Pro

Tags: r, shiny, connection-pooling, shiny-server, monetdb

With R and Shiny Pro it is possible to implement multi-user analytical applications.

When a database is used to store intermediate data, how to give access to multiple user access to the db becomes very relevant and necessary.

Currently I'm using MonetDB / MonetDB.R configured (as usual for R) as a single user access, which means that any user operation occurs in sequence.

I would like to implement some type of connection pooling with the DB.

From past SO [responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155727/how-to-use-connection-pooling-for-monetdb) the driver does not include connection pooling.

Are there alternatives within these toolsets?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any connection pool implemented for R DBI connections. The setup you describe seems rather special. You could just create a connection for every client session. MonetDB limits the amount of concurrent connections however, to increase this limit, you could set `max_clients` to a higher value, for example by starting `mserver5` with `--set max_clients=1000` or (if you use `monetdbd`), `monetdb set nclients=1000 somedb`. Of course, DBI connection pooling would also be a feature request for Shiny Pro and not for MonetDB.R .

Comment: I think I can implement this in a - perhaps simplistic way - but still resolving the issue.  Shiny Server Pro is associated to a license for a # of concurrent users.  In my case it is the minimal, 20 concurrent users.  This means simply that I can have max  20 different R processes  each connecting with monetdb: hence 20 users max.  I understand this should be manageable?

Comment: 20 concurrent users should be fine as long as they are not updating the same table.